# how to use dojo.all in case of loops and also requested calls methods expects callback function in their signature

Tags: javascript, dojo, ibm-case-manager, dojo.xhrget

All in my below scenrio,  `currentroles = [role1, role2];`

Currently, the code is like below. (Currently they are independent `async xhr` calls)

```
this.currentroles[0].retrieveWorklists(dojo.hitch(this,this.init),true);

this.currentroles[0].retrieveWorklists(dojo.hitch(this,this.init),true);
```

I want to put these two calls in `dojo.all` and use the combined results to process the results.

I did something below but getting error

```
all([this.currentuserroles[0].retrieveWorklists,this.currentuserroles[1].retrieveWorklists]).then(this.init);
```

Can you please help me how to use in this case?

Comment: Error :uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function - this is the error I am getting. I think retrieveWorklists method expectiing callback method as one of parameter from calling. so how to handle this type of cases. retrieveWorklists method is framework code and I cant change it.

Comment: What's the structure of role1 and role2 object .
retrieveWorklists must be a function of role1 | 2

Comment: we would need to know how retrieveWorklists is contructed,  does it use promises, because dojo.all is to wait for two deferreds to come back